# Function to find the max of 3 numbers in Python

Tags: python, list, function

I'm trying to write a function that takes the inputs and puts them into a list, then sorts the list, and finds the greatest number. I keep getting errors and I'm not really sure what's wrong. I'll post the current code that I have typed up already. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Code:

```
def findMax3():
    y = list(lst)
    y.sort(lst)
    y[0] == y[-1]

lst = int(input())
print(findMax3())
```

Comment: You need to pass in `lst`. `lst` doesn't exist inside the function. Also, in the future, polar day what the error is.

Comment: `findMax3` doesn't return anything. All you'll get back is `None`.

Comment: As @Carcigenicate says, you need to pass the list argument to your function but also return something from it (the sorted list perhaps? just the max? up to you..). Also you are converting the user input to integer when a list should be given.

Comment: `y[0] == y[-1]` does nothing.

Comment: You're saying I need to include lst as a parameter in the function? Like this: def findMax3(lst): ?

Comment: Yes, that would help. But you also need to `return` a result.

Comment: If you just need to find the `max` you don't need to sort the list - just `return max(lst)`

Comment: Zacadea, you **must** go find yourself a basic course or set of tutorials about Python. This is an extremely difficult way of learning a language.

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to pass in a variable - `lst` maybe?
2. You need to return value if you want your main to print something.
3. You need a constant input format for integer arrays, I will suggest `1 2 3 4 5` (space separated), that can be reversed to list using `map(int, input().split())`
4. Use the built-in `max`.
5. Do you want to limit yourself to 3 number arrays? if yes, use assertion.

That should be enough:

```
def findMax3(lst):
    assert len(lst) == 3
    lst.sort()
    return max(lst)

lst = map(int, input().split())
print(findMax3(lst))
```

Comment: What do you mean you need to pass in lst? And when I enter multiple inputs to your code, it only prints the first number I inputted and ignores the rest.

Comment: look on my 5 notes, input format for the code i provided should be like `89 45 23` in one line of input

Comment: Why sort the list?

Comment: it was in the OP question specs (`"then sorts the list..."`)

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected code:

```
def findMax3(lst):
    y = lst[:]
    y.sort()
    return y[-1]

lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(findMax3(lst))
```

I'd say `findMax()` would be a better name as this could find the maximum of lists of any length.

Bear in mind the following does the same thing:

```
lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(max(lst))
```

Comment: OP indicated list of integers. this code works with strings and sort by alphabetic rather than numeric.

Comment: @UrielEli: Thanks for pointing it out; I've made the edit (but it was fun to make it generic ;-)).

Answer (score 0):

Put the numbers in a list, then use max() function to get the maximum value in a list, like this:

```
#create an empty numbers list
lst=[]

#loop for getting input numbers
for i in range(1,4):    

    try:
        #here we get the input number
        my_new_number=int(raw_input("Please input the number "+str(i)+"/3 :\n"))
    except:
        #in case of it is not a number raise an alert
        print "not regular integer number"

    #here we check that number not exist
    if my_new_number not in lst:

        #add the current input number to the list
        lst.append(my_new_number)
    else:
        print "the number",my_new_number,"already exist in this list"

#show the maximum number of the list
print "The maximum number is",max(lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be interested in typing your list items one by one instead of using `split()` function to split your input. Also, to retrieve your list max, you have already a built-in `max()` function that you can use:

```
>>> num_list = []
>>>
>>> for i in range(3):
...     num = input("Enter number {}: ".format(i + 1))
...     num_list.append(int(num))
...
Enter number 1: 3
Enter number 2: 6
Enter number 3: 2
>>>
>>> max_num = max(num_list)
>>> print(max_num)
6
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, Ebe Isaac gave a good explanation and you should look at his solution and understand why it works.
There's a few issues with your code.

```
lst = int(input())
print(findMax3())
```

You're inputting a list of numbers that need to be separated by some non-numeric character, so you cannot use int() on your input value.

lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]

should give you what you want (with default separator being blank space). To learn more about this format, see list comprehensions.

Next, you call findMax3() but this function does not return a value so it will not have anything to print (see below). Additionally, it would be better to send it your list as an argument, this will save you from another line copying it later (see below).

```
lst = input().split()
print(findMax3(lst))
```

Now for your function:

```
def findMax3():
    y = list(lst)
```

You should probably send an argument (the inputted list) to the function. This argument can be renamed whatever you put in the parentheses after the name of the function. You are using y here so we can rewrite it as:

```
def findMax3(y):
```

and delete the y = list(lst) line.

```
y.sort(lst)
```

When using a method or function, it's a good idea to look up the documentation to identify what arguments it takes. You'll see that sort can take two arguments (key and reverse) neither are needed here so we can fix this line by changing it to:

```
y.sort()
```

The next line:

```
y[0] == y[-1]
```

is a Boolean expression and returns either True or False if the first element of the sorted list (y[0]) is equal to the last element of the sorted list (y[-1]). To be honest, I'm not really sure what you were trying to do here. Since the function is designed to find the max value of the list, it needs to return that value so we need to use return(). The max value will be the last of the list so you can do:

```
return(y[-1])
```

So if you want to keep the flow of your original code, it can work by changing it to:

```
def findMax3(y):
    y.sort()
    return(y[-1])

lst = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
print(findMax3(lst))
```

I hope this helps. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

As many have mentioned, you need to let your function know what list to find the max of. To do that, you need to put the name of the list in the parameter list of the function i.e. `findMax3(lst)`.

Your function will still not work because you are not returning anything from it. You need to use the `return` keyword followed by what to return in order to have the function give you a response. For example, `return 1` will return the value of `1` to anyone who called this function. Using that example, you need to decide what to return to the caller.

My version of `findMax3` without any other function calls:

```
def findMax3(*args):
    max3 = args[0]
    for n in args[1:3]:
        if n > max3:
            max3 = n
    return max3
```

This is pretty close to what the built in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) function will do given those same 3 inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a list then you can simply use the `max` function to get the highest number among 3 numbers in the list.

```
lst = [5, 2, 9]
print(max(lst))
# output
9
```

Or I assume you have three different numbers as input and then you can pass them to your desired method to get the highest number.

```
# function to get max among 3 integers
find_max(x, y, z):
    return max([x, y, z])

# take input
num1 = int(input("enter num1: "))
num2 = int(input("enter num2: "))
num3 = int(input("enter num3: "))

# call your function
print(find_max(num1, num2, num3))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we do not want to use the built in function for solving the problem we could always follow the below simple approach.

Using **max()** to find maximum of numbers is already shown in above few solutions.

Posting a sample solution without use of **max()**

```
num1=51
num2=6
num3=72

def find_max(num1,num2,num3):
    if (num1 > num2) and (num1 > num3):
        largest = num1
    elif (num2 > num1) and (num2 > num3):
        largest = num2
    else:
        largest = num3
return largest

print(find_max(num1,num2,num3))
```